# Screen blank after VNC session

Tags: windows-7, vnc, ultravnc

I have a strange problem occurring. I am using UVNC to login to a computer (has happened on several)
and just sometimes after I get disconnected (or I disconnect) the screen at the other end goes black.

I log back in via UVNC and the screen stops showing black and starts showing normally. Disconnect from VNC and it's fine. I wonder if maybe it happens when I get disconnected from UVNC rather than me closing the connection (the networks I'm connecting to are intermittent at the best of times).

The Video Mirror driver is not in use.

Any suggestions to stop this from happening ?

Comment: Can you use the mirror driver? It sounds like uVNC is getting hung up while releasing it's old style screen hooks.

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors? What kind of authentication are you using (Windows or VNC) through uVNC?

Comment: Single monitor, using uVNC authentication. The mirror driver use to cause this frequently so that's why I stopped using it, it's certainly not happened anywhere near as much in fact it hadn't happened for months until recently.